# Is there a way to update sum of row in 2D array?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Let's say I have a 2D array in Java. Is there a way such that if I have calculated the sum of a row and I change a few values in that row, the value of the sum is updated automatically? Is it possible too in C ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Store references to the values. [References](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science))

Comment: If your array strictly array of primitives?

Comment: Yes, use a function for modifying values that will check and update any other values.

Comment: u can build it using http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/

Comment: The short answer is: It is very unlikely in Java unless you store all of the array elements reference added to the sum

Answer (score 1):

Build a listener which will listen to changes in the 2D array. If any value gets changed, the listener will trigger a method which will update the sum.

Take a look at the [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html). You can use the `fireContentsChanged` method to specify the actions you want to take when values get changed.

I don't know if C has something like this. Maybe you can write your own Listener.